# Calculating expressions modulo n

Tags: haskell, modulo

When doing calculations modulo n with large numbers, you will encounter huge performency penalties when doing for example `mod (123456789^987654321) n`. Instead you have to use your own `^` that internally calculates mod n also for intermedite calculations.

Sure, I can easily implement my own functions, but then I have to explicitly say "mod n" for each operation. Instead one could build an numeric expression tree and defer actual calculations, and in the end state modulo n only once. (see my code below)

I started on this to clearly show what I mean, but I wonder if there already exists implementations of this, it seems quite useful so somebody ought to have implemented it.

```
module Modulo where

data Expr =
    V Integer 
  | Plus Expr Expr
  | Mult Expr Expr
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Num Expr where
  (+) = Plus
  (*) = Mult
  fromInteger = V

eval :: Integer -> Expr -> Integer
eval m (V i) = i `mod` m
eval m (Plus e1 e2) = (eval m e1 + eval m e2) `mod` m
eval m (Mult e1 e2) = (eval m e1 * eval m e2) `mod` m

fifteen :: Expr
fifteen = 10 + 5

test = eval 13 fifteen
```

Comment: Do you need the `m` in `mod m` to be changeable at runtime, or is it enough to have it fixed at compile time? If compile-time is enough case, you could simply define a modulo-arithemtic `Num`-instance for some newtype'd `Integer`...

Comment: I want it to be changeable at runtime. Sorry, I should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oleg did something of this kind, where you make an instance for modulo arithmetic, but for a arbitrary modulus.  [Implicit configurations.](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/types.html#Prepose)

Comment: I don't get it. Are you linking to a scientific paper or an actual implementation? If it is an implementation, can you provide a code example?

Comment: Did you bother checking out the link?  It has the paper, and also an implementation.  There is also a README file that describes what the files contain.

Comment: I skimmed the abstract on the web-page and found nothing about modulo, apparently the theory was deeper than what first met the eye. Now I found the implementation and paper. You're absolutely correct, it was what I was looking for. Sorry for my initial frowning, I so much assumed somebody would link to a github repo, not a paper.

Comment: I'm actually stunned that I didn't find anything else on hackage. I coulda swore I saw something at some point... anyway, ekmett has a tidied and supported version of the configuration portion alone here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection